# Adding multiple records with duplicate information Rails Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to find a way to add multiple records that will share information without the user needing to enter the same information every time.

I am creating a library where a user can add a book.  The form will appear:

Genre
Author

Title
Publisher
ISBN

I would like for the user to be able to fill out the Genre and Author, and then create multiple books under that genre and author without having to create the book one at a time and having to fill back in the Genre and Author.  I would like the form to have:

Genre
Author

Title
Publisher
ISBN

Title
Publisher
ISBN

With the user being able to add and remove more "Title Publisher and ISBN" sections so that when the user clicks Create.  It will create however many records (in this case 2) that will have the same Genre and Author but different Title's Publisher's and ISBN's.
I am assuming this will need to be done in AJAX?  I am a total newb when it comes to js and ajax so if you could point me to tutorials or something that will help that would be great. I am currently watching railscasts about nested models forms: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 but this deals with multiple models.  This is just one which i would think would be easier but just do not know what strategy I should be looking for.

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Nested_forms by ryanb
https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

This does what I need it to.